# ActiveRecord relationships and migrations for new web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm a Rails beginner trying to build my first web app.

In my web app **Physiotherapists** can add **Patients** and create **ExercisePlans** from a list of **Exercises**. I sketched out the model relationships as follows underneath. Is this the correct way to do it?

I am mostly concerned about the following:

- Is a join table the correct way to match exercises to exercise_plans?
- Do I need a join table to match physiotherapists to exercise_plans?

**RELATIONSHIPS**

```
Physiotherapist
  has_many :patients
  has_many :exercise_plans      

Patient
  has_many :exercise_plans
  belongs_to :physiotherapist

Exercise
  has_many :exercise_plans

ExercisePlan
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :physiotherapist
  has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises
```

**MIGRATIONS**

```
class CreatePhysiotherapists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :physiotherapists do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :company_name    
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.timestamps  
    end
```

---

```
class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name   
      t.string :email
      t.integer :physiotherapist_id #the physiotherapist to which the patient belongs
      t.timestamps  
    end
```

---

```
class CreateExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :exercises do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :category
      t.string :bodypart
      t.text :instructions      
      t.timestamps
    end
```

---

```
class CreateExercisePlans < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :exercise_plans do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :exercise_id #an array of exercises that are in the plan
      t.integer :physiotherapist_id #the physiotherapist who created the plan
      t.integer :patient_id #the user for whom the exercise plan is made
      t.timestamps  
    end

#join table for the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with exercises
    create_table :exercise_plans_exercises do |t|
      t.integer :exercise_id
      t.integer :exercise_plan_id 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. However, I'd use `has_many :through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`. It is a much more flexible approach and allows for a customization of exercise for each specific exercise plan. For example, you might want to store a number of repetitions or duration in `Activity` model. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

```
ExercisePlan
  has_many :activities
  has_many :exercises, through: :activities

Exercise
  has_many :activities
  has_many :exercise_plans, through: :activities

Activity
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :exercise_plan
```

2) No, there's no need for an additional join table.

Notes:
You don't really need to have physiotherapist_id in exercise_plans, because you already have it in patients. You can `exercise_plan.patient.physiotherapist`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I fix this? Does this mean ExercisePlan `has_many Exercises :through exercise_plans_exercises`? Also thanks for the note.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. You can use some other name for `Activity` and you also need a migration for activities table.

Comment: Great! I get it now. This activities model also allows me to add repetitions or exercise duration to customize the plan even further. Thanks a lot!